# Insert missing values from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, primary-key

I have a table with a PK that grows fairly quickly, but since rows are fairly consistently deleted, it becomes a very sparse table quickly as such:

```
   ID     VALUE
 ----------------
   1     'Test'
   5     'Test 2'
   24    'Test 3'
   67    'Test 4'
```

Is there a way that I can automatically insert the next value in the missing IDs so that I don't grow that ID extremely large?  For example, I'd like to insert 'Test 5' with ID 2.

Comment: Why do you care if the ID is large? Or if there are gaps? Does this ID really mean anything? If it does, can you explain why?

Comment: You **cannot** "go back" and fill gaps with identities - what for? `INT` gives you **over 2 billion** possible values. If you use up one value every second, all days long, every day of the year - you will need **66.5 years** before you hit the 2 billion limit ....

Comment: If records are consistently deleted, then it seems like you'll be fighting an uphill battle.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It's simply a stylistic issue.  Why have a sparse identity when you can have a cleaner, compact one.

Comment: How is it "cleaner"? They're meaningless ID values. Especially if they no longer reflect the order in which they were created.

Comment: @marc_s It's not actually an Identity column, it's just a primary key attached to an INT column.  I know that there are a lot of possible values, I'd just prefer to keep them compact.

Comment: The amount of work and checking to make sure you're not using a duplicate value just doesn't justify the effort, in my opinion. It's just numbers - who cares how big they are? Typically, no user will ever see those anyway.....

Comment: Compression will help with keeping them "compact" more than your tactic will. Do you know how much more space 66 takes compared to 4? How about 12987235 compared to 4? Exactly the same! Unless you have used compression.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Maybe it's just cleaner looking to me.  I can't actually think of a reason why it'd be better, but since we are simply manually inserting the value anyway, I figured it wouldn't hurt to keep the numbers small.

Comment: It's not worth it. Just make the column an IDENTITY column and go solve bigger, real problems.

Comment: How do you handle time-based queries? How do you know if you're talking about a row with ID=4 that is valid now, or that was valid (different data, but same ID - it's been reused.....) three years ago? Don't do it - it's neither worth it, nor a real problem. Let it be - get over it - get on with your dev life, you probably (hopefully!) have more interesting challenges to tackle!

Comment: If this isn't an identity column, why do the question title and tags indicate it is?

Comment: If you have a clustered index on there (you do have clustered indexes, right?) then going back and filling in will give you issues with performance and cause fragmentation.

Comment: @marc_s  The creation time needs to be different for different users anwyay, so we deal with that in a different table.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Bad titling on my part.  It's an "ID" but not and Identity in DB terms.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted my answer about identity since they are not involved.  It would be interesting to see if you are using this as a clustered index key, since to fill in gaps would violate the rule of thumb of strictly increasing values.

To just fill in gaps is relatively simple with a self-join and since you have a primary key, this query should run quickly to find the first gap (but of course, how are you handling simultaneous inserts and locks?):

```
SELECT lhs.ID + 1 AS firstgap
FROM tablename AS lhs
LEFT JOIN tablename AS rhs
    ON rhs.ID = lhs.ID + 1
WHERE rhs.ID IS NULL
```

And inserting batches of records requires each insert to be done separately, while IDENTITY can handle that for you...

Comment: This one will work but because of all of the advice I've received, I plan to just stick with the sparse column.  thanks for everybody's help.

Comment: Remember that we vote up questions which show effort on the part of the author as well as being a correct answer :)

Comment: @DanAndrews I'll give you one

Answer (score 2):

**I'm not suggesting doing what you're trying to do, but if you want to do it, this is how.  I am only answering the question, not solving the problem.**

In your proc, you'd what to lock your table while doing this so that you don't get one the sneaks in.  By using something link this:

```
EXEC @result = sp_getapplock @Resource = @LockResource, 
                                 @LockMode = 'Exclusive'
```

AND

```
EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = @LockResource
```

**TABLE**

```
DECLARE @table TABLE ( id INT, val VARCHAR(20) )
```

**DATA**

```
INSERT  INTO @table
        (
          id,
          val
        )
        SELECT  1,
                'Test'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2,
                'Test'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  5,
                'Test 2'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  24,
                'Test 3'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  67,
                'Test 4'
```

**Queries**

```
INSERT  INTO @table
        SELECT TOP 1
                id + 1,
                'TEST'
        FROM    @table t1
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1
                                    1
                             FROM   @table
                             WHERE  id = t1.id + 1 )
        ORDER BY id

INSERT  INTO @table
        SELECT TOP 1
                id + 1,
                'TEST'
        FROM    @table t1
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1
                                    1
                             FROM   @table
                             WHERE  id = t1.id + 1 )
        ORDER BY id

SELECT  *
FROM    @table
```

**RESULT**

```
id  val
1   Test
2   Test
5   Test 2
24  Test 3
67  Test 4
3   TEST
4   TEST
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do that.

As already explained by others in the comments, you gain nothing by re-filling gaps in the numbers.

Plus, you might even unintentionally mess up your data if you refer to these IDs **anywhere** else:
Let's say that there once was a row with `ID 2` and you deleted it.
Then you insert a complete new row and re-use `ID 2`.
Now if you have **any** data anywhere that references `ID 2`, it suddenly links to the new value instead of the old one.

*(Note to nit-pickers: Yes, this should not happen if referential integrity is set up properly. But this is not the case everywhere, so who knows...)*

Comment: It not only happens with referenetial integrity but with reports or cusotmers who were told somethinga t a the time. Suppose I call to see what happened to my order 1234 and now it is someone else's order 1234 becasue it accidentally got deleted.

Comment: I'd upvote you a million times if I could, you gain nothing but the potential for problems by doing this and for something that isn't even a requirement, but just because the developer thinks it looks nicer.

Answer (score -2):

As said before: don't worry about the unused ID's.

It is however good practise to optimize the table when a lot of deletes happen.

In MySQL you can do this with:

```
optimize table tablename
```

Comment: in ms sql you should reorganise or rebuild your indexes on a temporary base. (every night or so)

Comment: True, but that causes fragmentation.

Comment: @JNK sorry, FILE fragmentation.

Comment: @DanAndrews based on what?  If the database has sufficient slack space it won't affect file level fragmentation at all

Comment: @JNK 'If the database has sufficient slack space it won't affect file level fragmentation at all'.  We see this at work.  On large databases if you frequently (daily) rebuild and reorganize you'll get file fragmentation.  We monitor the disk closely.  As the database grows, the file grows, which takes more sectors on your disk - causing fragmentation.  However you are right, if you have enough slack space and you've defragged the drive, you *should* be good for awhile.